# UE4 Problem with Waves Watermaterial and Mesh

Tags: c#, c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

At the moment I work at my Water Material for my Ocean.
I know how to how to create Material with Sinus Wave GerstnerWaves and all what's needed.

But the Problem is when I apply this to a plane the whole plane is moving. And not waves on the plane.
I know there is a Grid or something but I don't know more about it.
Please someone help me with it and tell me how to correctly apply it to a plane or tell me what exactly I else need.

And maybe you guys can tell me some links or Tipps how to stop the water when there is a landscape and adding curls then.

Would be great.
Thank You :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your plane has too little vertices. Try with a plane that has higher poly count so the individual waves are visible.

The reason this is happening is because your plane only has 4 vertices. While you want a visible mesh that has more vertices it's just not possible with 4 vertex plane.